# Is there a way to see how many bits compose an arbitrary variable X in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an arbitrary variable X, and I would like apply a function and get as the output the number of bits X takes up. I know that I can use 'whos', but I want a usable output of the number of bits of X.

Is there any (built-in) function that can do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look to [whos documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html).

You can do this :

```
variableStruct = whos('x');

nbByte = variableStruct.bytes
```

If the variable doesn't exist, you structure is empty.

**EDIT**

With [subref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), you can do it in one liner like this :

```
byte = subsref(whos('x'),struct('type','.','subs','bytes'));
```

Comment: No problem, Just accept the answer if it good for you. And `isempty` can be a great function to see if the variable exist or not. Or the alternative is `exist('x','var')`

Comment: The function [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) might also be useful here if doing this programmatically. It must be called from within a function (M-file or anonymous). So: `varname = @(v)inputname(v);` `str = varname(x);`.